# java web application failing to build

Tags: java, apache, ant, build, annotations

I'm new with annotations and building applications, so I apologize if it's too easy or I asked the wrong type question. I have a custom annotation like this :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Handler {
    Class value();
}
```

Now in a java file, say AB.java, I used this annotation like this

```
@Handler(Msg.class)
public void handleMsg(Msg msg) {
    ...//some code
}
```

Now when I tried to build the application, by doing this from the location of my build.xml file

> ant rebuild content

it says

> BUILD FAILED

for this reason

> /home/../somePath/AB.java:800 error: cannot find symbol
>
> @Handler(Msg.class)
>
> symbol: method value()
>
> location: @interface Handler

I'm running java version "1.7.0_101" if it matters. Does it matter if maybe this was written with java version "1.7.0_45". Can someone explain why this's happening even though the class Msg exists in my project files?